# Can I define something in .vimrc to speed up pasting of large amounts of data?

Tags: vimrc, cut-copy-paste, options

Occasionally, I paste large amounts of data into vim, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> in my terminal emulator (in Linux). This takes several seconds before vim is responsive again. I have tried two [other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18258561/1944384), which work well: either `"+P`, or temporarily `:set noswapfile` before pasting.

I have tested launching vanilla vim, using `vim -u NONE`, and the problem still persists. As a reference, this [5600-character lorem ipsum](https://pastebin.com/raw/gZCFiv0r) takes ~3 seconds to paste with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. It's almost instantaneous with `"+P`.

I only need the paste alternatives with large data and vim. In all other situations I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. In vim, this also has the added advantage of working in insert mode. It's only *after* I paste long data, when I regret my life choices.

Is there a way to automatically apply some workaround, so that is it consistently quick to paste with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>?

Comment: Do you `set paste`/use `'pastetoggle'`/use umimpaired.vim’s `yop` before you paste? IIRC they significantly speed up pasting, and the last one is easy on muscle memory. `'pastetoggle'` is useable in Insert mode though

Comment: Oops, I forgot that I had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7053522/1944384) in `~/.vimrc`. It seems like the current version of vim doesn't need `set paste` any more. I tested without it, but it's still super slow either way. Using the linked code, the terminal isn't constantly updating through the paste, but it's only a relatively minor improvement (~4 s vs. ~6 s for a 300 000 character paste), as opposed to using `"*P` which is almost instantaneous.

Comment: 300000 chars? Personally I’d drop to a shell and do `pbpaste >> file` or equivalent. You might get away with `:read !pbpaste` but honestly I expect a performance hit with that much input`

Comment: This was more for testing purposes; I do still see a long lag for even half a page worth of text. (It also appears to be non-linear. It's not like it's a .5 second pause here.)

Comment: I often paste large logs I may get through a webpage in vim so I can search through them properly (so, definitely more than half a page of text) and pasting is instantaneous (I'm on Linux). Maybe try a fresh vim (in a VM maybe, no plugins or vimrc). If pasting is fast there, then reintroduce your vimrc and plugins bit by bit till you find out which one is at fault.

Comment: @Shahbaz I tested with vanilla vim and it's still present. I also added some more specific data regarding time. For some reason a shorter string is taking ages today, consistent with what I normally saw.

Comment: The reason it's so slow is because Vim processes it like you typed the text (there isn't really a standard way if distinguishing from typed text vs. pasted text), so it evaluates stuff like determining indentation, syntax highlighting, autocmds, etc. loads of times. So disabling as much of that as possible should help (`set paste` does some of that, but not all). Using [`:profile`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3Aprofile) might be helpful in displaying where most time is being spent.

Comment: I've found it helpful to reduce the size of the window to something tiny, in addition to setting paste, though I would guess setting lazyredraw might have a similar effect.

Comment: @MartinTournoij Doesn't `xterm-bracketed-paste` in vim 8 suggest that vim *can* tell the difference? I'm trying to use `:profile` after `vim -u NONE`, but now I can't replicate the problem at all. There was no large CPU usage when I tested previously, so I have no idea what has changed. I can still replicate the problem with my normal `~/.vimrc`, so I'll do a bit more troubleshooting.

Comment: Have you tried `:set swapsync=`? That should prevent Vim from waiting until the swapfile is completly written.

Comment: I'd try disabling the syntax before pasting, it might help

Comment: With both nvim & vim, macos, latest versions from homebrew, your 5600 character sample pastes quickly with `vim -u NONE`. Instantly for nvim, nearly instantly with vim. What version OS are you seeing this behavior? And what kind of terminal app?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Sorry, I finally got around to testing your command. Yes… it helps quite a bit! On a large chunk of text (`lorem-ipsum-generator -p 100`), it improves pasting from tens of seconds to ~0.5 second. It's still not as instantaneous as `"+P` though. It's pretty good, but I'm not totally happy with it, because IMO vim *should* paste both ways at the same speed without having to disable certain features. However, it's a pretty good workaround, and if you post it up, I'll upvote. I wonder if it is indicative of what the real problem is though?

Comment: well, for `"+` vim knows that the input is coming from the system clipboard while for your other method of pasting it seems vim doesn't know. So it has to process the input as typed.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I hinted at this above, but since vim 8 has `xterm-bracketed-paste`, doesn't that meant that vim *does* know that the pasted text is coming from the clipboard? i.e. it can differentiate between pasted and typed text.

Comment: @Sparhawk It is not clear to me, that your terminal actually uses `xterm-bracketed-paste` you haven't said what terminal you used and `xterm-bracketed-pasted` needs terminal support. So my guess is, it is not being used (or not correctly configured), don't know

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Good point. It certainly was functional in the past, as I saw issues such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5585129/1944384) or [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/15722/1278), and needed to enable `xterm-bracketed-paste` to fix it. However, when I now start `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE`, I can't confirm the paste errors any more. Do you know if there's a way to confirm if xterm-bracketed-paste` is functioning?

Comment: @Sparhawk I'm not 100% certain about this, but I believe if you can paste with `Ctrl-V` starting from _normal_ mode, then bracketed paste must be functioning, as if it weren't, Vim would instead execute the contents of your clipboard as if you typed them in normal mode (which may at some point end up in insert mode, depending on the contents of your clipboard).

Comment: Thanks @Rich. I tested again. With `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE`, I can paste in both normal and insert, so presumably bracketed paste is still functioning.

Comment: @Sparhawk But with `-u NONE`, you said [pasting is fast](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18710/can-i-define-something-in-vimrc-to-speed-up-pasting-of-large-amounts-of-data?noredirect=1#comment32306_18710), anyway? What about using your normal, problematic config?

Comment: @Rich Erm, yeah, it looks like I did say that, but I just tested again, and with `-u NONE` I still experience the slow pasting. I think part of the problem might be that the lag is a bit erratic, and also perhaps depends on the precise text I'm pasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to post and accept this as the best solution proposed, since it was a comment over a year ago that was never converted to an answer.

As per [Christian Brabandt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/71/christian-brabandt)'s [comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18710/can-i-define-something-in-vimrc-to-speed-up-pasting-of-large-amounts-of-data#comment32311_18710), `:set swapsync=` speeds up the paste by a lot.

Benchmarking with a 100 paragraph lorem ipsum (`lorem-ipsum-generator -p 100`):

- `"+p` is near instantaneous
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> takes ~3.6 s
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> with `:set swapsync=` takes ~0.3 s

So it's not *quite* as fast as `"+p`, but it's pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting `lazyredraw`.

Comment: Unfortunately this makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

you could try disabling backup/swap files. if pasting the contents into memory is all you want, disabling disk writes might be faster.

from https://stackoverflow.com/q/743150/11374957

```
set nobackup       "no backup files
set nowritebackup  "only in case you don't want a backup file while editing
set noswapfile     "no swap files
```

you could do a comparison with/without those settings and see if it's any faster. another option: do the same test, but turn on a disk I/O monitoring app first and see if that shows any meaningful spike (with backup files enabled) vs. drop (with `nobackup`, `nowritebackup`, `noswapfile`).

Comment: It's maybe twice as faster with those three settings than without, but still considerably slower than `"+p`. Also, in the long term, I certainly don't want to disable those settings. Given that `"+p` is near instantaneous with those settings set, I feel like there is some other issue here.

Comment: Well, have you tried the suggestion with the `swapsync` setting as I mentioned before?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Oops, sorry, I must have missed that. I'm away from this system for a week or so, but I'll have a look when I'm back.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using something like `<Ctrl-V>` or `<Cmd-v>` or equivalent you're doing it wrong. Doing that, the text is pasted into the vim buffer, as if you were typing it. That can have a lot of delay because of several vim options such as autoindent, etc.

Typically you can use either `"+p` or `"+]p` (this pastes keeping current indent level in mind) to paste text near instantly as it is.

VIM also has a little known Paste Mode, which essentially is a special mode that disables a bunch of vim settings to allow hassle free pasting without having to worry about vim treating the text in some way, shape of form other than just adding to the buffer. You can have a look at `:help 'paste'` for more info, there is also a helpful setting `pastetoggle` to assist with easy enabling / disable of paste mode.

However, in my experience just using the paste operator instead of a native `<ctrl-v>` version is significantly better.

> NOTE: It would be more memory & compute efficient to do this outside of vim with shell redirection.

Comment: I don't get any autoindent when I paste with `ctrl`+`v`, possibly because of `xterm-bracketed-paste` (but as per the comments to the question, we're not sure). Either way, I don't think it's "as if you were typing it" for me. After `:set paste`, pasting is still as slow as ever, although now the text is outputted to the screen bit-by-bit as it pastes, instead of all at the end. Using the paste operator is preferred, but as per my question, I often forget!

Answer (score 0):

What about just remap ctrl-v in insert mode to paste from system clipboard?

```
inoremap <c-v> <esc>"+p
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: I'm guessing they'd also need to modify their terminal config to pass the Ctrl-V onto Vim, as in their current setup Vim won't ever see the `CTRL-V` keypress: it will only receive the text inserted by the terminal.

Comment: Yes, good idea, but if the terminal never sees ctrl+v as paste, then I could never paste into the CLI, for example.

Comment: @Sparhawk, which terminal are you using? AFAIK, Linux terminal does not support ctrl-v to paste into the terminal. You need to use Shift+Insert.

Comment: Terminator, which does support ctrl+v for paste. shift+insert sends the primary selection instead.

Comment: Then I think you may use another terminal, for example, kitty or Alacritty.